How to communicate between udp server and udp client by dpdk using same net interface card
i want to build application upd server and upd client for test, but i only have one dpdk interface, i'm new to dpdk, here is my upd server/client demo, and i got error when i run udp client app.

    sudo ./dpdk_udp_client --proc-type=secondary
    EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 2
    EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
    EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
    EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket_11301_143edb614d0e
    EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
    EAL: VFIO support initialized
    EAL: Using IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU)
    EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_ena (1d0f:ec20) device: 0000:28:00.0 (socket 0)
    EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
      Cause: Cannot create mbuf pool

=============== upd client demo ================
    #include <rte_eal.h>
    #include <rte_ethdev.h>
    #include <rte_mbuf.h>
    #include <rte_udp.h>
    #include <rte_ip.h>
    #include <rte_ether.h>
    #include <rte_malloc.h>
    #include <rte_lcore.h>
    #include <rte_cycles.h>
    #include <rte_errno.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    
    #define MBUF_CACHE_SIZE 250
    #define NUM_MBUFS (4096-1)
    #define IPv4(a, b, c, d) ((uint32_t)(((a) << 24) | ((b) << 16) | ((c) << 8) | (d)))
    
    struct Data {
        uint64_t a;
        uint64_t b;
        uint64_t c;
        uint64_t d;
        uint64_t e;
        uint64_t f;
    };
    
    static struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool;
    
    int dpdk_init(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
        if (ret < 0) 
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error with EAL initialization\n");
    
        // mbuf_pool = rte_mempool_lookup("MBUF_POOL");
        // if (mbuf_pool == NULL)
        //     rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot find mbuf pool\n");
        mbuf_pool = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("MBUF_POOL", NUM_MBUFS * rte_lcore_count(),
                                            MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());
    
        if (mbuf_pool == NULL)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create mbuf pool\n");
    
        return ret;
    }
    
    void udp_client_send(struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool, uint16_t port_id, const struct Data *data) {
        struct rte_mbuf *mbuf = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(mbuf_pool);
        if (mbuf == NULL)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot allocate mbuf\n");
    
        struct rte_ether_hdr *eth_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbuf, struct rte_ether_hdr *);
        struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ip_hdr = (struct rte_ipv4_hdr *)(eth_hdr + 1);
        struct rte_udp_hdr *udp_hdr = (struct rte_udp_hdr *)(ip_hdr + 1);
        struct Data *payload = (struct Data *)(udp_hdr + 1);
    
        memset(eth_hdr, 0, sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr));
        rte_eth_macaddr_get(port_id, &eth_hdr->src_addr);
        eth_hdr->ether_type = rte_cpu_to_be_16(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_IPV4);
    
        ip_hdr->version_ihl = RTE_IPV4_VHL_DEF;
        ip_hdr->type_of_service = 0;
        ip_hdr->total_length = rte_cpu_to_be_16(sizeof(struct rte_ipv4_hdr) + sizeof(struct rte_udp_hdr) + sizeof(struct Data));
        ip_hdr->packet_id = 0;
        ip_hdr->fragment_offset = 0;
        ip_hdr->time_to_live = 64;
        ip_hdr->next_proto_id = IPPROTO_UDP;
        ip_hdr->hdr_checksum = 0;
        ip_hdr->src_addr = rte_cpu_to_be_32(IPv4(127, 0, 0, 1));
        ip_hdr->dst_addr = rte_cpu_to_be_32(IPv4(127, 0, 0, 1));
    
        udp_hdr->src_port = rte_cpu_to_be_16(1234);
        udp_hdr->dst_port = rte_cpu_to_be_16(5678);
        udp_hdr->dgram_len = rte_cpu_to_be_16(sizeof(struct rte_udp_hdr) + sizeof(struct Data));
        udp_hdr->dgram_cksum = 0;
    
        *payload = *data;
    
        mbuf->l2_len = sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr);
        mbuf->l3_len = sizeof(struct rte_ipv4_hdr);
        mbuf->data_len = sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr) + sizeof(struct rte_ipv4_hdr) + sizeof(struct rte_udp_hdr) + sizeof(struct Data);
        mbuf->pkt_len = mbuf->data_len;
    
        uint16_t nb_tx = rte_eth_tx_burst(port_id, 0, &mbuf, 1);
        if (nb_tx < 1) {
            rte_pktmbuf_free(mbuf);
            std::cerr << "Failed to send packet\n";
        }
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        dpdk_init(argc, argv);
    
        uint16_t port_id = 0;
        if (rte_eth_dev_count_avail() < 1)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "No Ethernet ports - bye\n");
    
        rte_eth_dev_start(port_id); // rte_eth_dev_configure(port_id, 1, 1, NULL);  //rte_eth_dev_start(port_id); // 
        rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(port_id, 0, 128, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port_id), NULL, mbuf_pool);
        rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(port_id, 0, 128, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port_id), NULL);
        // rte_eth_dev_start(port_id);
        rte_eth_promiscuous_enable(port_id);
    
        struct Data data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        udp_client_send(mbuf_pool, port_id, &data);
    
        return 0;
    }

============= upd server ==============
    #include <rte_eal.h>
    #include <rte_ethdev.h>
    #include <rte_mbuf.h>
    #include <rte_udp.h>
    #include <rte_ip.h>
    #include <rte_ether.h>
    #include <rte_malloc.h>
    #include <rte_lcore.h>
    #include <rte_cycles.h>
    #include <rte_errno.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    
    #define MBUF_CACHE_SIZE 250
    #define NUM_MBUFS (4096-1)
    #define IPv4(a, b, c, d) ((uint32_t)(((a) << 24) | ((b) << 16) | ((c) << 8) | (d)))
    
    struct Data {
        uint64_t a;
        uint64_t b;
        uint64_t c;
        uint64_t d;
        uint64_t e;
        uint64_t f;
    };
    
    static struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool;
    
    int dpdk_init(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
        if (ret < 0) 
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error with EAL initialization\n");
    
        mbuf_pool = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("MBUF_POOL", NUM_MBUFS * rte_lcore_count(),
                                            MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());
    
        if (mbuf_pool == NULL)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create mbuf pool\n");
    
        return ret;
    }
    
    void udp_server_receive(uint16_t port_id) {
        struct rte_mbuf *bufs[32];
        uint16_t nb_rx;
    
        while (true) {
            nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id, 0, bufs, 32);
            if (nb_rx > 0) {
                for (uint16_t i = 0; i < nb_rx; i++) {
                    struct rte_mbuf *mbuf = bufs[i];
                    struct rte_ether_hdr *eth_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbuf, struct rte_ether_hdr *);
                    struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ip_hdr = (struct rte_ipv4_hdr *)(eth_hdr + 1);
                    struct rte_udp_hdr *udp_hdr = (struct rte_udp_hdr *)(ip_hdr + 1);
                    struct Data *data = (struct Data *)(udp_hdr + 1);
    
                    // 处理数据包
                    std::cout << "Received data: " << data->a << ", " << data->b << ", " << data->c << ", "
                              << data->d << ", " << data->e << ", " << data->f << std::endl;
    
                    rte_pktmbuf_free(mbuf);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        dpdk_init(argc, argv);
    
        uint16_t port_id = 0;
        if (rte_eth_dev_count_avail() < 1)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "No Ethernet ports - bye\n");
    
        struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = {};
        rte_eth_dev_configure(port_id, 1, 1, &port_conf);
        rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(port_id, 0, 128, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port_id), NULL, mbuf_pool);
        rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(port_id, 0, 128, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port_id), NULL);
        rte_eth_dev_start(port_id);
        rte_eth_promiscuous_enable(port_id);
    
        if (rte_lcore_id() == 0) {
            udp_server_receive(port_id);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
    

tks a lot....
fix my pr / show some new way / gave me some advice / share doc to me

In general, the idea of using UDP over the same DPDK port for inter-process communication seems rather peculiar, unless loopback of some sort is configured, with flow rules directing server's packets to the client's receive queue and vice versa.
Also, the use of secondary process is probably not what is intended here. Secondary process is not supposed to be able to access DPDK port's control plane, it is only supposed to attach to the datapath/statistics.
Instead, consider to use a regular (kernel-bound) interface for the server instance (via DPDK vdev port of type af_packet — see the document) and, for the client instance, a DPDK vdev port of type tap (with remote pointing at the server's interface — also see the document). In this case, different values for --file-prefix option of EAL shall be used for the two instances. In example, for the server, use --file-prefix server and, for the client, --file-prefix client.

fyi - this is really not your decision whether people choose to post comments about your answer, especially if asking for clarification, correcting an error, etc. This should not be part of your answers (I removed it from here accordingly)
